Using Python API thougt Julia PythooCall not working
For some time now, I have been trying to use a Python API (ENTSO-E) to retrieve data from the ENTSO-E website via PythonCall in Julia. When using native Python, I have no issues installing all packages in a dedicated environment and executing functions to retrieve data. The problems arise when I try to call these functions from Julia using PythonCall. Initially, I tried to call the functions directly from the entsoe package (notably the query_generation_per_plant function), but it includes an argument named end, which is a reserved word in Julia. (I attempted to use a dictionary to pass the arguments without success.) A direct call seems to be a dead end. As a second attempt, I tried putting this function in a Python function that would be called via PythonCall, thus avoiding the reserved word issue, but without success. Here is a minimal example:
Python code dans un fichier nommé entsoePerso.py (dans le même répertoire que les fichiers source julia)
from entsoe import EntsoePandasClient
import pandas as pd  
import pyarrow

def DL(date,country_code,chemin):
        # Initialisation du client avec votre clé API
        print("in Dl_gen")
        API_KEY = 'apiKey'  # Remplacez par votre clé API ENTSO-E
        client = EntsoePandasClient(api_key=API_KEY)
        psr_type = False    # non gérer dans le cadre de cette requête
        eic = False         # non gérer dans le cadre de cette requête
        # Téléchargement des données de production
        try:
            data = client.query_generation_per_plant(
                country_code, 
                start=pd.Timestamp(date, tz='UTC'), 
                end=pd.Timestamp(date + pd.Timedelta(hours=23), tz='UTC'),
                psr_type=psr_type, 
                include_eic=eic)
            print("Données téléchargées pour ",date)
            #data.to_parquet(chemin+country_code+'_'+date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.entsoe', engine='pyarrow', compression='snappy')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {e}")

code Julia
using PythonCall
using DataFrames
sys = pyimport("sys")
sys.path.append(dirname(@__FILE__))

function Entsoe(startDate::String,stopDate::String,country_code = "FR")
   dates = DateTime(startDate,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"):Hour(1):DateTime(stopDate,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")+Hour(23)
   for date in dates
      pyimport("entsoe2fem").DL(date,country_code,"\Data")
   end
end

dataEntsoe = Entsoe("2024-12-08 00:00:00","2024-12-09 00:00:00")


in order to execute this code CondaPkg has to be installed in julia in order to install entsoe-py and pyarrow
] conda add entose-py
conda add pyarrow

The goal is to create a Julia custom package that allows downloading data from the ENTSO-E website."
